# Duplicate columns in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Let's suppose I have a simple Numpy matrix:

```
np.matrix([[1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1],
           [1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1]])
```

How do I efficiently remove all duplicate columns except the first occurrence without having to loop through?

Which would result in:

```
np.matrix([[1, 1, 2, 0, 3],
           [1, 2, 0, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Does the order of columns matter for the output?

Comment: It should not, but I would be interested in experimenting with both preserving and not preserving order.

Answer (score 3):

If the order is not important, you can use `unique`

```
X = np.matrix([[1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1],
               [1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1]])

np.unique(X, axis=1)
```

results in

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2, 0, 3]])
```

If preserving the order is important, it will be a bit slower:

```
X = np.matrix([[1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1],
               [1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1]])

idxs = np.sort(np.unique(X, axis=1, return_index=True)[1])
answer = X[:, idxs]
```

answer will then be:

```
matrix([[1, 1, 2, 0, 3],
        [1, 2, 0, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Simply index into cols : `X[:,np.sort(np.unique(X, axis=1, return_index=1)[1])]`.

Comment: The code doesn't actually work. Divakar's answer does.

Comment: I have just fixed it. There was a small typo in the code. The [1] was outside the parenthesis